# Finding a numerical value

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following system:

[image: System]

When `t < 2.5`I know that `alfa=0`
First I had to write a linear aproximation of the system with `S>>k`. I did that and I obtained the system:

```
dX/dt = p * X
dS/dt = (p * X) / y
```

I solved the this system in mathematica and I obtained `{ s -> Function[{t}, C[1]-((-1+E^(p*t)) C[2])/y], x -> Function[{t}, E^(p*t)C[2]] }` .

My task is to use the solution for `X` and the data that I have wich is in the format: `{{Time, S, X}, {0, 45.84, 0.15}, {0.15 45.29, 0.19}, {0.3, 44.66, 0.25}}` to obtain a numerical value for `p` and I have a hint: `Plot the logarithm of X against the time, and estimate the slope` Someone said that the linearized solution is: `Log[X[t]]==Log[X[0]]+p*t`, the use `LinearModelFit` to fit my (logged) data to a line, `p` is the slope.

```
t1 := 0
s1 := 45.84
x1 := 0.15
t2 := 0.15
s2 := 45.29
x2 := 0.15
t3 := 0.3
s3 := 44.66
x3 := 0.25
```

Solving the equation for `x`, for `t1=0` gives me the constant value `C[2]=0.15`
so `x[t]==0.15*e^(p*t)`

```
solLin1 = Solve[Log[x2] == Log[x[0]] + p*t2, p]
p->1.57
solLin2 = Solve[Log[x3] == Log[x[0]] + p*t3, p]
p->1.70
```

My question is if I used correct the function `Log[X[t]]==Log[X[0]]+p*t` in this way? And I don't understand the part `use`LinearModelFit`to fit my (logged) data to a line,`p`is the slope`

Answer (score 2):

In what follows `data` contains the list of observations *without* the header.

Evaluating `Part[data, All, {1, -1}]` will return a list of pairs `{t,X}` (*time* and *X* value pairs). This list, will be transformed accordingly, in order to be used with `LinearModelFit` (see below).

The solution for `X[t]` of the differential system is given by `X[t]->Exp[p t]C[2]` and can be written as `Log[X[t]]==Log[C[2]] + p t` (taking logs on each hand side and turning `->` into `==`).

This last (algebraic) expression can be interpreted as a linear equation in `t` of the form eg `y==a+b t`. This form can be estimated using [`LinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearModelFit.html?q=LinearModelFit) after applying a simple transformation to the available data.

According to the documentation, `LinearModelFit` requires the data that are passed to it, to be in the form `{{x11, x21, ..., x1n, y1}...}` (the dependent variable is the *last* entry in every row of data).

Since we'll be using the logarithmic transformation of the solution for `X[t]`, we are going to need to transform all the `X` values (the dependent variable in our regression) into (natural) logs. This is accomplished thus: `MapAt[Log, Part[data, All, {1, -1}], {All, -1}]`.

Finally, evaluating `lmf=LinearModelFit[transd,t,t]; lmf["BestFit"]`, where `transd` holds the transformed data (see above) produces

> ```
> -1.90346 + 1.70275 t
> ```

The (point estimate of the) slope or $\hat{ρ}$ is equal to `1.703` (approx.).

---

**edit**

code I've used

```
Clear[naught]

(* returns the symbols in 'x' appended with '0' eg 'naught[x,y]' evaluates to '{x0, y0}' *)
naught[x__] := Map[ToExpression[StringJoin[ToString[#], "0"]] &, {x}]


ClearAll[lin]

SetAttributes[{lin}, Listable]

(* returns a linear approximation of 'f' around 'naught[x]' *)
lin[f_, x__] := Module[{x0 = naught[x], deriv0, f0, diff0},
  f0 = f @@ x0;
  deriv0 = D[f[x], {{x}}] /. Thread[{x} -> x0];
  diff0 = {x} - x0;
  f0 + Total[diff0 deriv0]
 ]


ClearAll[sep]

SetAttributes[{sep}, Listable]

(* returns a list of coefficients for variables 'x' present in 'f'; 
   the first entry contains constant terms eg 'sep[a+bx+cy]' returns '{a,b,c}' *)
sep[f_, x__] := Module[{coefs = Coefficient[f, {x}]},
  Flatten[{Simplify[f - coefs.{x}], coefs}]
 ]
```

I have defined the *rhs* of the differential system as

```
f1[x_, s_] := p s x/(s + k) - a x
f2[x_, s_] := a (si - s) - p/y s x /(s + k)
```

Evaluating

```
lin[{f1, f2}, X, S]
```

returns the linearised system

> ```
> {
>  (-a + (p S0)/(k + S0)) (X - X0) - a X0 + (p S0 X0)/(k + S0) + (S - S0) (-((p S0 X0)/(k + S0)^2) + (p X0)/(k + S0)), 
>  a (-S0 + si) + (S - S0) (-a + (p S0 X0)/((k + S0)^2 y) - (p X0)/((k + S0) y)) - (p S0 (X - X0))/((k + S0) y) - (p S0 X0)/((k + S0) y)
>  }
> ```

and interpreting the fact that `S>>k` implies `S+k->S` along with the fact that since the time index in the provided data is below `2.5`, the value of `a` is inferred to be zero (see question)

```
q = sep[lin[{f1, f2}, X, S], X, S] /. {k + S0 -> S0, k -> 0, a -> 0} // Simplify
```

returns

> ```
> {{0, p, 0}, {0, -(p/y), 0}}
> ```

which can be shown to be equal to the derived *rhs* of the system; indeed

```
Total[{1, X[t], S[t]} #] & /@ q
```

returns

> ```
> {p X[t], -((p X[t])/y)}
> ```